# How to update the URL of the current tab when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
const selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
require('chromedriver');
const By = selenium.By;

const driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
const url = 'https://example.com';
driver.get(url);

driver.findElement(By.css('header nav .header-nav-item-sign-in > .header-nav-link')).click();

// finding elements on the new URL that has been opened by clicking on the link

driver.findElement(By.css('#user_session_email')).sendKeys('example@email.com');
driver.findElement(By.css('#user_session_password')).sendKeys('example');
driver.findElement(By.css('button.button.primary[type=submit]')).click();
```

I open 'example.com' and find an element which is a link. I click on the link and try to locate an element on the new URL which has been opened in the same tab. I get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

How can I update the URL in Selenium?

Note: the link used is a dummy link. Actual page has the following element. I am unable to update the URL selenium is present in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a basic UI automation problem. You need to make sure that the page you open here is completely loaded and the elements are ready to be acted upon with actions like sendKeys.

Best way is to use a wait statement and ensure that the element is loaded(code below) before you do any actions on the element.

```
//wait till the element is located. Throws timeout error if the element is not located in 10 seconds
const user_session_email = driver.wait(
   until.elementLocated(By.css('#user_session_email')),
   10000  
);

//act on the element
user_session_email.sendKeys('example@email.com');
```

This method has an advantage that it will not wait for the full 10 seconds specified, if the element is located before that.

Comment: This doesn't work as Selenium is still searching the DOM on the initial page. To verify this, I created a similar action which clicks(2nd click) on a link on the initial page after the 1st click. It doesn't search the DOM of the present URL (the one after clicking on the 1st link).

Comment: How are you sure that Selenium is searching the initial page? Could you please share the code you used to test this?

I tried the below code to check the page title before finding the elements and it works perfectly fine.

driver.get(url).then(function(){
 driver.getTitle().then(function(title){console.log(title)})
});
const nb = driver.wait(
  until.elementLocated(By.css('#test')),
  20000  
);
nb.click();
const inp = driver.wait(
  until.elementLocated(By.css('#test2')),
  20000  
).then(function(){
 driver.getTitle().then(function(title){console.log(title)})
});

Comment: I tried finding an element(link) present in the initial page after clicking the 1st link and clicking it. The 2nd link was clicked even when Selenium was showing the webpage for the 1st link and after a few seconds, I was there on the page of the 2nd link. Can you tell me a way to check the current URL of the page in Selenium Javascript so that I can confirm?

Comment: You can check the current url using driver.getCurrentUrl() method.

driver.get(url).then(function(){ 
driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(_url){
console.log(_url)
}) 
}); 
const nb = driver.wait( until.elementLocated(By.css('#test')), 20000 ); nb.click(); const inp = driver.wait( until.elementLocated(By.css('#test2')), 20000 ).then(function(){ 
driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(_url){
console.log(_url)
}) 
});